# Como mandar un pdf con PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me genera un pdf

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Image('../../imagenes/3.png' , 1 ,-5, 60 , 50,'PNG');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
$pdf->Ln(15);
$pdf->Cell(120, 18, 'SOLICITUD DE COTIZACION', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->SetXY(160,18);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'FOLIO: '.$idCotizacion,0); 
$pdf->SetXY(160,25);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'FECHA: '.$fechaCotizacion,0); 
$pdf->Ln(15);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B',10);
$pdf->Cell(100,10,"DATOS DEL SOLICITANTE");
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '',10);
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Nombre: '.$contacto);
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Telefono: '.$numero);
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Correo: '.$email);
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B',10);
$pdf->SetXY(120,45);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'DATOS DE LA RUTA ',0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '',10);
$pdf->SetXY(120,50);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Origen: '.$origen); 
$pdf->SetXY(120,60);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Destino: '.$destino);
$pdf->SetXY(120,70);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Kilometros: '.$km); 
$pdf->SetXY(10,80);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B',10);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'FECHA DE SERVICIO');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '',10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,85);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Fecha de inicio: '.$fechaInicio);
$pdf->SetXY(10,90);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Hora de inicio:  '.$horaInicio);
$pdf->SetXY(10,95);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Fecha de termino: '.$fechaTermino);
$pdf->SetXY(10,100);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Hora de termino:  '.$horaTermino);
$pdf->SetXY(10,105);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Dias de duracion:  '.$duracion);
$pdf->SetXY(120,80);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Numero de Plazas:  '.$numeroPlazas);
$pdf->SetXY(120,90);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,3.5,'Comentarios:  '.$comentarios);
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->Output();
```

El cual funciona bien, lo que quiero hacer es que después de que se haya generado el `pdf` mandarlo a un correo con *`PHPMailer`* pero no se como adjuntarlo.

---

Utilizo este código en el ouput:

`$pdf->Output($idCotizacion.".pdf","F");`
y despues con estas lineas

```
$mail->addAttachment( $idCotizacion.'.pdf' );
$mail->Send();
```

Hago el envío, si me guarda el `pdf` pero no me manda el correo, el código para enviar es este:

```
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->Mailer="smtp";
$mail->Helo = "www.gmail.com"; //Muy importante para que llegue a hotmail y otros
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port=25; //depende de lo que te indique tu ISP. El default es 25, pero nuestro ISP lo tiene puesto al 26
$mail->Username="praxedes1314@gmail.com";
$mail->Password="********";
$mail->From="praxedes1314@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName="Jose Luis";
$mail->Timeout=60;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

//Enviamos el correo
$mail->AddAddress('praxedes1314@hotmail.com'); //Puede ser Hotmail
$mail->Subject='tu asunto';
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Cuando olvides detalles de tu pregunta **la puedes editar** para modificarla. Hay una opción para ello, que dice **Editar**. Está entre la pregunta y las etiquetas. Así evitas escribir parte de la pregunta como si fuese una respuesta. Te sugiero que lo hagas cuando sea posible, que edites la pregunta añadiendo lo que pusiste en la respuesta de más abajo  y que luego borres aquella. Gracias.

Comment: si ya encontraste la respuesta, porfavor añadela como respuesta atu propia pregunta y seleccionala como la solucion, o porfavor selecciona la respuesta que te ayudo a solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero genera tu pdf mandandolo a una variable:

```
$archivoPdf = $pdf->Output('','S');
```

Luego adjuntalo como base64:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($archivoPdf,'nombreX.pdf','base64');
```

De esa forma lo haces todo al vuelo y no ocupas nada de espacio en disco.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardarlo en tu servidor o temporalmente, luego agregarlo al mensaje como un adjunto con su comando respectivo.

```
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.pdf');
```